# Finding multiples of five in a vector using a function

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, vector

> Write a function called findMultipleOfFives that takes a vector of integers as parameter (passed as constant reference) . Your function should return true if every number in the vector is a multiple of the number 5. The function should return false otherwise.
>
> For example, for a given vector variable, vector all_values{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, the function findMultipleOfFives will return true. However, for a given vector variable, vector all_values{10, 24, 30, 40, 5}, the function will return false.

The code I wrote:

```
//Name
//This program will determine if a vector has multiples of fives


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


string findMultipleOfFives(vector<int> &all_values);

vector<int> all_values{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

int main()
{
    cout << "This program will determine whether a vector is full of multiples of five." << endl;
    findMultipleOfFives(all_values);
}

string findMultipleOfFives(vector<int>& all_values)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        all_values[count] = 5;
        if (all_values[count] % 5 == 0)
        {
            all_values[count]++;
            return "True";
        }
        else
        {
            return "False";
        }
    }
}
```

An error shows up where I call the function in my `main()` function:

> Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction

Other than figuring out what that error means and what I've done wrong, I'm stuck on how to read through each element of the vector.  I know to determine if a single value is a multiple of five using modulus, but I'm not catching on to how to cycle through and determine this for each value and return true or false.

Comment: Do you expect everyone to count the lines in the code to find the 17th one, or perhaps you would like to explicitly point out the line with the error? And what is the purpose of assigning every value in the vector with 5, only to see if it has a remainder when divided by 5. The answer, of course, will always be zero. Finally, it seems to be very obvious from reading the assignment that the intent for your function is to return `bool` values `true` and `false` instead of literal text strings. What exactly led you to believe that this function should return `std::string`'s, instead of `bool`s?

Comment: And then you edited your question and removed the line that assigned 5 to every value in the vector. What happened? Did you copy/paste it wrong, and what kind of a copy/paste error inserts an extra line like that? Or, maybe this still isn't the real code?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I edited and changed that entire section because I am continuously trying to fix it? I'm not used to using stackoverflow, the website I usually use inserts the line numbers when you upload.  I'm just asking for help, no need to be condescending.

Comment: @yellogs just because you are fixing the code as we go along does not mean you should re-write the question to match your fixes. That invalidates comments and answers that have been posted.  If you want to show edits, that is fine, but they should be done in addition to the previous content, not to replace it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Gotcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are trying to modify the `vector` while you are looping through it.  You don't need to do that, nor do the instructions ask you to do that.

Second, the instructions ask you to return a boolean, not a string.

Third, your function is not looping through the whole vector.  `std::vector` has a `size()` member to get the actual number of elements, and an `operator[]` to access the elements.  But even with that size value, your loop is `return`'ing on the 1st iteration, so you are only comparing the 1st element and ignoring the other elements.  The instructions clearly say to return `true` if *all* of the elements match the condition.

Try this instead:

```cpp
//Name
//This program will determine if a vector has multiples of fives


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool findMultipleOfFives(const vector<int> &all_values);

int main()
{
    cout << "This program will determine whether a vector is full of multiples of five." << endl;
    vector<int> all_values{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    cout << boolalpha << findMultipleOfFives(all_values);
}

bool findMultipleOfFives(const vector<int>& all_values)
{
    if (all_values.empty())
        return false;

    for (size_t count = 0; count < all_values.size(); count++)
    {
        if ((all_values[count] % 5) != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, `std::vector` has `iterator`s that you can use instead, eg:

```cpp
bool findMultipleOfFives(const vector<int>& all_values)
{
    if (all_values.empty())
        return false;

    for (vector<int>::const_iterator iter = all_values.begin(); iter != all_values.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if ((*iter % 5) != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or, using a range-based `for` loop in C++11 and later (which uses `iterator`s internally):

```cpp
bool findMultipleOfFives(const vector<int>& all_values)
{
    if (all_values.empty())
        return false;

    for (int num : all_values)
    {
        if ((num % 5) != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have it all wrong.

In your code:

```
string findMultipleOfFives(vector<int>& all_values)  // the exercise call for a function 
                                                     // that returns bool value, 
                                                     // not a string
{
   for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)  // you are looking for multiples of 5, 
                                            // not loop though the first 5 elements.
   {
       all_values[count] = 5;              // Why are you changing the original array?
       if (all_values[count] % 5 == 0)
       {
           all_values[count]++;            // Why are you still changing the original array?
           return "True";                  // You are returning before the end of the loop.
                                           // all elements must be mults of 5  
                                           // to return true.
       }
       else
       {
           return "False";
       }
    }
}
```

Here's one way to write it.

```
bool AllAreMuliplesOfFive(const vector<int>& v) // Note the use of const, we do not need to change 
                                                  // or destroy the caller's data.
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)  // looping through all elements in v
                                          // v.size() returns a size_t 
   {
       // test condition
       if (v[i] % 5 != 0)   // multiple of 5? 
          return false;     // no, since we need all to be multiple of 5 for success
                            // return false now.
   }
   return true;  // all elements have passed the test!
}
```

Comment: "*`return true; // all elements have passed the test!`*" - unless the `vector` is empty, that is. Since this is just a class assignment, that is likely to not be the case, but it is a good thing to learn to handle in practice. That is why I added the `empty()` check in my example.

Comment: This was very helpful, I appreicate it.

Comment: I agree.  I did write it as an exercise.  Using std::all_of() does not require a function, after all.

Comment: @yellogs  no problem.  Since you are beginning, you should try writing your function in pseudo code before starting to write code.  You will find that it helps a lot to collect your ideas and write down the algorithm first.

Answer (score 1):

This should just be an algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool findMultipleOfFives(std::vector<int> const& all_values)
{
  return std::none_of(all_values.cbegin(), 
                      all_values.cend(), 
                      [](int v) { return v % 5; });
}
```

As @RemyLebeau points out, writing this as an `all_of` might be easier to read:

```
bool findMultipleOfFives(std::vector<int> const& all_values)
{
  return std::all_of(all_values.cbegin(), 
                     all_values.cend(), 
                     [](int v) { return v % 5 == 0; });
}
```